# Using a slider for opacity of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a bit of trouble having a slider change the opacity value of my div.  Here is a fiddle of what I've been working with: https://jsfiddle.net/yfmLk1ad/1/

```js
$('#bgopacity').on('slide', function(value) {
   $('.background-color').css({
       opacity: value * '.01'
   });
});
```

```css
.background-color {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-color"></div>
<form>
    <label>Color Opacity</label>
    <input type="range" name="bgopacity" id="bgopacity" value="50" min="0" max="100" step="1" onchange="rangevalue.value=value">
    <output id="rangevalue">50</output>
</form>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to make use of `change` event. And to take the value of the slider like this `($(this).val()`, not passing as parameter. This update the rectangle when you finished to choose the value.

```js
// Opacity Slider
$('#bgopacity').on('change', function (value) {
    $('.background-color').css({
        opacity: $(this).val() * '.01'
    });
});
```

```css
.background-color {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>Color Opacity</label>
    <input type="range" name="bgopacity" id="bgopacity" value="50" min="0" max="100" step="1" onchange="rangevalue.value=value">
    <output id="rangevalue">50</output>
</form>
<div class="background-color"></div>
```

---

For **real time** update you can use `input` event. This is updated when the value is changing.

```js
// Opacity Slider
$('#bgopacity').on('input', function (value) {
    $('.background-color').css({
        opacity: $(this).val() * '.01'
    });
});
```

```css
.background-color {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>Color Opacity</label>
    <input type="range" name="bgopacity" id="bgopacity" value="50" min="0" max="100" step="1" onchange="rangevalue.value=value">
    <output id="rangevalue">50</output>
</form>
<div class="background-color"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, replace

```
$('#bgopacity').on('slide', function (){...});
```

with

```
$('#bgopacity').on('change', function (){..});
```

Instead of `value` use  `$(this).val()`

See it [working](https://jsfiddle.net/yfmLk1ad/10/)