# Slider Opacity control for element by id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the opacity by Element Id with the slider from the 2nd code snippet.
What's a good method to implement the slider in this case?

```html
<p id="s1">See effect here</p>
<select onchange="myFunction(this);" size="14">
<option>0 <option>0.1 <option>0.2 <option>0.3 <option>0.4
<option>0.5 <option>0.6 <option>0.7 <option>0.8 <option>0.9
<option selected="selected">1
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(x) {
 // Return text 'See effect here' of the selected option
 var opacity = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text;
 var el = document.getElementById("s1");
  if (el.style.opacity !== undefined) {
  el.style.opacity = opacity;
  } else { alert("Your browser doesn't support this example!"); } }
</script>
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
.slidecontainer {width: 100%;}
.slider:hover {opacity: 1;}
</style>
<div class="slidecontainer">
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5">
</div>
```

Comment: So... you want to use the `<input>` element to change the opacity, but the opacity of *which* element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better will be slider. You will get slider value very easy. Here is a example

```js
var range = document.getElementById("range");
var imgOne = document.getElementsByClassName("img1")[0];
var imgTwo = document.getElementsByClassName("img2")[0];

range.addEventListener("change", function() {
    imgOne.style.opacity = this.value / this.max;
    imgTwo.style.opacity = (this.max - this.value) / this.max;
});
```

```css
.img1, .img2 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="50" value="25"><br><br>

<img class="img1" height="200" width="200" src="http://www.technocrazed.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/beautiful-wallpaper-download-11.jpg" />

<img class="img2" height="200" width="200" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSLg8Fo8YK5SNLqmZUUCjaUh_2Y57jxBgkmjOwxj7dNSui2jZcb" />
```

Answer (score 1):

this working fine :
[Using a slider for the opacity of a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271965/using-a-slider-for-opacity-of-a-div)

```js
// Opacity Slider
$('#bgopacity').on('input', function (value) {
    $('#s1').css({
        opacity: $(this).val() * '.01'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>Color Opacity</label>
    <input type="range" name="bgopacity" id="bgopacity" value="50" min="0" max="100" step="1" onchange="rangevalue.value=value">
    <output id="rangevalue">50</output>
</form>
<p id="s1">See effect here</p>
```